# Eclipse gives error message on class variable declarations?

Tags: java, eclipse, network-programming, socketchannel

I am practicing networking in java, and I intend to send a file via  SocketChannel, with the host and port specified by the user. However when I declare the variables Eclipse gives the error message:

"Syntax  error on tokes, delete these tokens"
EDIT: (This error message pops up next to the declarations of port and host)

This is my code:

```
public int port;
public String host;

public class Client {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter host/ip: ");
    Scanner inputHost = new Scanner(System.in);
    host = inputHost.next();

    System.out.print("Enter port: ");
    Scanner inputPort = new Scanner(System.in);
    port = inputPort.nextInt();




    Client client = new Client();
    SocketChannel channel = client.createChannel();
    client.sendFile(channel);
```

Comment: Both the `post` and `host` variables need to be declared inside the scope of the  `Client` class.

Comment: ohh sorry silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

The port and host variables need to be defined in the class variable and based on their usage in static method main they need to be declared static.